# Scroll View doesn't scroll when touching and holding then swiping

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uisegmentedcontrol, uiview-hierarchy

I have UIScrollView with other UIView elements inside. My other UIView elements are mostly segmented controls. If I click on a UISegmentedControl and hold for a second and then try to scroll, then no scrolling happens. I can only scroll when my finger touches and swipes immediately. I checked other iOS applications such as mail. The behavior was that you touch and hold on a mail, then it's highlighted, but as soon as finger moves away, the scrolling happens and highlighting is undone. How can I implement this behavior?

Comment: If you have added segmented control over the Scroll View, you can add it over the controller's view. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the property of UIScrollView. The property canCancelContentTouches was set to NO. Because of that, touch events were handled by subviews of scroll view and swiping didn't cause scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow one of these steps:

1. If you are using UISegmentedControl over you UIScrollView, instead of that, add the UISegmentedControl over your controller's view.
2. If you want to use UISegmentedControl over your scrollView, then you have to create a custom scrollView by creating a subclass of UIScrollView and use an image view instead of UISegmentedControl adding the labels which can act as the segments. This is because your UISegmentControl itself is a touch handler and it breaks the UIResponder chain. So, the scrolling might face issues during the touch events.

Please let me know if any of these works. Thanks :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already have a controller and I add the segmented control to the controller's view.